# How to remove publish button from the post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the publish post button in WordPress posts. I want to use neither CSS nor JS. I just want to know if there is an answer to remove it from a hook.
This is the button I want to remove (also when it is Publish Post too. I don't want to see any button at all):

[image]

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: why do you want to remove the button?

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar because there is a type of role that hasn't to be able to publish or send for review, only save drafts

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look and I cant find a hook that would conditionally allow you render or skip the submit button.

The code for this button can be found at `wp-admin -> includes -> meta-boxes.php` line 365.

Comment: i advise not to change anything in wordpress core files, it would generate another errors and can breakdown the site

Comment: I also agree with this. I was offering the location of the file for the OP to understand why there was no hook available for this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I already found the files but I still can't find a solution that doesn't involve javaScript

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your comments that you need a user role that can only save drafts (**not** publish posts, send them for review etc).

Take a look at WordPress [Roles and Capabilities](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

> Contributor (*slug: ‘contributor’*) – somebody who can write and manage their own posts **but cannot publish them**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks! But contributor role can Submit for Review :(